# handlebar js if condition statement check with json object value

Tags: json, if-statement, handlebars.js, parameter-passing, templatebinding

I have the issue of handling an if conditon in handlebars js

```
{"lstModel":[{"name":"Sizes","values":[{"value":"L"},{"value":"XL"},{"value":"M"}]},{"name":"Colours","values":[{"value":"Green"}]}]}


     <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="filter">
        <form class="col-md-6" id="filter-{{name}}">
                                <label>Select {{name}}</label>
                            {{#if name.Sizes}}
                                <div class="size-selector">
                                {{#values}}
                                    <div class="entry">{{value}}</div>
                                {{/values}}
                                </div>
                           {{else if name.Colours}}
                                <div class="color-selector">
                                {{#values}}
                                    <div class="entry" data-value={{value}} style="background: {{value}};">&nbsp;</div>
                                {{/values}}
                                </div>
                            {{/if}}
</form></script>
```

The issue I'm facing is when I'm trying to check with the values of json in if condition its not showing going inside of condition. Please help.

Comment: I see multiple issues with your code. 1) You need to loop through your array `lstModel` using {{#each}} helper. 2) `{{#if name.Sizes}}` is not a right syntax and neither ``{{else if name.Colours}}``. 3) You need to loop through the `values` array as well. Do some research at http://handlebarsjs.com

Comment: Hello Gibin, Can you please send me the how should be the json format to work with {{#each}}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template should be rewritten like below for the conditions and loops to work correctly

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="filter">
  {{#each lstModel}}
    <form class="col-md-6" id="filter-{{name}}">
      <label>Select {{name}}</label>
      {{#ifCond name 'Sizes'}}
        <div class="size-selector">
          {{#each values}}
            <div class="entry">{{value}}</div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      {{else}} 
        {{#ifCond name 'Colours'}}
          <div class="color-selector">
            {{#each values}}
              <div class="entry" data-value={{value}} style="background: {{value}};">&nbsp;</div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        {{/ifCond}}
      {{/ifCond}}
    </form>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

And you need to register a custom 'handlebars helper' `ifCond` to match specific strings.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Finally, the output(compiled HTML) will looks like this,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="filter">
  <form class="col-md-6" id="filter-Sizes">
    <label>Select Sizes</label>
      <div class="size-selector">
          <div class="entry">L</div>
          <div class="entry">XL</div>
          <div class="entry">M</div>
      </div>
  </form>
  <form class="col-md-6" id="filter-Colours">
    <label>Select Colours</label>
        <div class="color-selector">
            <div class="entry" data-value=Green style="background: Green;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I declared two templates and check the json with the jquery if condition and then populate the two templates.

Comment: You don't need to check with jquery. It can be done through the custom helper `ifCond` here.

Comment: Can you please send me the json format to work with Custom Helper ifCond? Because before handlebar js I was using mustache js. So I formatted the Json according to that.

Comment: I've just used the json which you have provided in your question.

Comment: Please join - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167075/chat-gibinealias-shubham-mondal

Comment: Sorry I can't chat there I need 20 Reputation to chat with you at chat room.

Comment: Ok my bad. Please use this site  - http://tryhandlebarsjs.com
Copy-paste my code on the first section, the json on the second and the helper code on the third and try it for yourselves.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)